# I have a "sales" table and need to program a way to determine the commission I receive based on preset rules. How do I do this?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "sales" table. I want to determine the total commission I have made based on this rule:

First $250,000 sales, I get 5%. Next $250,000 sales, I get 3%. Next 250,000 sales, I get 2%. Finally, any more sales thereafter I get 1%. Obviously, I want this measure to update itself as the sales figures continually get updated.

I am totally lost on how to program this. Normal if statements like this won't suffice:

```
avgbps = if('sales'[Q2 Sales] <= 250000000, 'sales'[Q2 Sales] * 0.05)
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. This should work

```
avgbps = 
IF(SUM('Q2 Sales'[Sales])<= 250000000,SUM('Q2 Sales'[Sales])*0.05,
 +
 IF(SUM('Q2 Sales'[Sales])> 250000000 && SUM('Q2 Sales'[Sales])<=5000000 ,SUM('Q2 Sales'[Sales])*0.03
 *
 IF(SUM('Q2 Sales'[Sales])> 5000000,SUM('Q2 Sales'[Sales])*0.01)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible method than multiple `IF`'s to handle this kind of problem is with a table and using `VLOOKUP`

I created a table named `Commissions` as below:
[image]

**Tier** and **PerCent** are obvious, and can be extended if you want.

**Base** is calculated:

```
(CurrentTier - PreviousTier) * PerCent + PreviousBase
```

Then, with your amount in A1, you can use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Commissions,2)+(A1-VLOOKUP(A1,Commissions,1))*VLOOKUP(A1,Commissions,3)
```

[image]